# Oracle database parenthesis error

Tags: database, oracle

I'm trying to find what is the error in this query, but I can't find the parentheses error. They look correct to me. The error code is:

`ORA-00907: missing right parentheses`

Here is the query:

```
CREATE TABLE GRADE
(
    COURSE_NO VARCHAR(100),
    STUDENT_ID VARCHAR(100),
    GRADE VARCHAR(1),
    PRIMARY KEY (COURSE_NO, STUDENT_ID)
    FOREIGN KEY (COURSE_NO)
    REFERENCES COURSE(COURSE_NO),
    FOREIGN KEY (STUDENT_ID)
    REFERENCES STUDENT(STUDENT_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (GRADE)
    REFERENCES GRADE_POINT (GRADE)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a comma missing at this line:

```
PRIMARY KEY (COURSE_NO, STUDENT_ID)
```

Your SQL must be:

```
CREATE TABLE GRADE
(
COURSE_NO VARCHAR(100),
STUDENT_ID VARCHAR(100),
GRADE VARCHAR(1),
PRIMARY KEY (COURSE_NO, STUDENT_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (COURSE_NO)
REFERENCES COURSE(COURSE_NO),
FOREIGN KEY (STUDENT_ID)
REFERENCES STUDENT(STUDENT_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (GRADE)
REFERENCES GRADE_POINT (GRADE)
);
```